# Chef: set service dependencies

Tags: chef-infra

I'm deploying my `*.war` applications on my installed wildfly using chef.

The problem is that one of these applications has a service dependecy that is installed but it's not started up to the end of the recipe is performed.

I'd like to set that `mongod` must to be started before wildfly_deploy is performed:

In order to install mongo I'm using `mongodb3` recipe:

```
include_recipe 'mongodb3::default'
```

and in order to install wildfly:

```
include_recipe 'wildfly::install'
(((***)))
wildfly_deploy 'authz.war' do
  path '/tmp/authz.war'
end
```

I need that on `(((***)))` mongod is started.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Chef inherently respects the order of code in your recipes, so if the include_recipe is before the deploy resource then it will happen first. Just remember the two-phase system (compile vs. converge, read more at https://coderanger.net/two-pass/) so Mongo will be installed before the deploy resource converges, but after it is compiled. If the issue is just that the `mongodb3` recipe isn't starting the system service, you can use a `service` resource to do that, though the specifics depend entirely on the internals of that recipe.